# setting variable to the return type of a function

Tags: c, function, struct

I can't seem to figure out why this will not work, I am passing the 'aHouse' variable a function which returns a House. I am new to C so am still trying to get my head around a few things.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct house {
    int id;
    char *name;
} House;

House getHouse()
{
    House *myHouse = NULL;

    char c = getchar();
    myHouse->id = 0;
    myHouse->name = c; /*only single char for house name*/

    return *myHouse
}

int main()
{
    House *aHouse = NULL;

    aHouse = getHouse();
}
```

Comment: There are big troubles in this code: you cannot use the myHouse pointer after you initialize it to NULL.

Comment: This is not homework, just a simple abstraction of some code of mine that wasn't working.
@didier ahh ok, this is starting to make more sense, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:
You are using a NULL pointer and assigning values to it in the 'getHouse' function.  This is undefined behaviour and should give an access violation.

Also, you are returning a House object by value from getHouse and trying to assign to a pointer type.  A pointer and a value are two different things.

You don't need pointers here at all unless you want to allocate your Houses dynamically on the heap.

```
House getHouse()
{
    House myHouse;

    char c = getchar();
    myHouse.id = 0;
    myHouse.name = c; /*only single char for house name*/

    return myHouse
}

int main()
{
    House aHouse;

    aHouse = getHouse();
}
```

EDIT: for the sake of efficiency, you could implement it like this though:

```
void getHouse(House* h)
{ 
    char c = getchar();
    h->id = 0;
    h->name = c; /*only single char for house name*/
}

int main()
{
    House aHouse;    
    getHouse(&aHouse);
}
```

EDIT again:
Also in the House structure, since the name can only be one char, don't use a char* for name, just use a char.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. Pointers are starting to make more sense. If my main function did point to *aHouse there would be no guarantee that House would still be there after I exited the function right?

Comment: If getHouse returned a pointer to a local variable of type House, then this is also undefined behaviour, because the local variable would be allocated on the stack, and then deallocated from the stack when the function exits.  If you needed the object to still be valid when the function returns, then you would need to allocate it n the heap (e.g. with malloc()).  The pointer would then remain valid until the memory it points to is freed (e.g. with free()).  If you do allocate on the heap then you need to be careful to free the memory later to avoid leaks.  I'd suggest reading up on it.